# ECHO! Echo! echo. (echo)

Tags: code-golf, networking

Your challenge, should you choose to accept it, is simple:

Implement [RFC 862](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc862), also known as the Echo Protocol:

### The Echo protocol

An echo service simply sends back to the originating source any data it receives.

#### TCP Based Echo Service

One echo service is defined as a connection based application on TCP. A server listens for TCP connections on TCP port 7.  Once a connection is established any data received is sent back.  This continues until the calling user terminates the connection.

#### UDP Based Echo Service

Another echo service is defined as a datagram based application on UDP.  A server listens for UDP datagrams on UDP port 7.  When a datagram is received, the data from it is sent back in an answering datagram.

#### Scoring

- The score is one point for every byte of code as encoded in UTF-8 or a language-specific code page, whichever is smaller.
- If the program incompletely implements RFC 862 by providing only UDP or only TCP, the score is doubled.
- If the program incorrectly implements RFC 862 by either using a port other than 7 or by dropping or transforming certain bytes due to language limitations or corner cutting, the score is quadrupled. (This stacks with the preceding point if applicable.)
- If the program is invalid, the score is [ω](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinity).

#### Rules

A valid program:

- Does not use [standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default).
- Per connection:

  - Accepts connections and receive incoming data.
  - Sends outgoing data in an amount that is always less than or equal to the amount of data received.
- Does not invoke programs external to itself. (Spawning children to deal with multiple connections is fine, spinning up `inetd` or its local equivalent is not.)
- Does not use library functions specifically designed to start and maintain an echo service.

This is code golf, so lowest score wins.

Comment: We require challenges to be self-contained, at the moment we have to read external resources to determine what we are supposed to do. Voting to close as unclear until you fix that.

Comment: @DenkerAffe: Addressed.

Comment: AKA: HTTP Cat program.

Comment: `Does not use library functions specifically designed to start and maintain an echo service`? What? Seriously?

Comment: @epicTCK I'm not sure I understand your objection.

Comment: Infinity is `∞`, not `ω`

Comment: @anatolyg `∞` isn't a number, `ω` is; and the score needs to be a number.

Comment: Why don't you just say if the program is invalid it's disqualified..

Comment: I think the rule about port 7 is pointless.  In general, you'll need to be root to use ports <1024, regardless of language.  I assume that this challenge is allowing entries to run as root with no extra penalty.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma, byte count. `7` is one byte.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma, it's better to use fixed one-digit port as it voildn't affect program length.

Comment: @Qwertiy which should be fine for just about any language that has a [`bind()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/bind.html) equivalent, which I assume will be just about every entry.  It just seemed a bit strange to explicitly state this as a rule (with such a harsh penalty)

Comment: These penalties are ridiculous. If you want to require supporting both TCP and UDP, then just require it. With these harsh penalties, it's essentially required anyway in order to have a good score.

Comment: Why do you have the encoding rules? They seem pointless.

Comment: IPv4 or IPv6 protocols? Assuming IPv4.

Comment: I think at the core it's a fine challenge but the scoring is nonsensical. Typically either a solution is valid or it isn't; we don't really allow "almost correct" solutions in general. Also, the UTF-8 thing seems unnecessary to specify since by default we allow answers to be scored in bytes of whichever encoding is most natural. I recommend posting challenge ideas to the [Sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140) where they can get feedback prior to going live.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## JavaScript (Node.js) 102 Bytes (51 * 2)

```
require("net").createServer(s=>s.pipe(s)).listen(7)
```

You can add UDP for a total of **132 bytes**, as seen below:

```
require("net").createServer(s=>s.pipe(s)).listen(7),(u=require("dgram").createSocket("udp4")).on("message",msg=>u.send(msg)).bind(7)
```

Was tested on node.js v5.2.0

Make sure to run with `sudo` on Unix descendants (OS X, Linux, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

## Python, <s>299</s> <s>295</s> <s>265</s> 263

```python
from threading import*
from socket import*
a='',7;S=socket
u=S(2,2);u.bind(a)
def U():
 while 1:u.sendto(*u.recvfrom(4**8))
Thread(None,U).start()
def C(c,x):
 while c.send(c.recv(1)):1
s=S(2,1);s.bind(a);s.listen(1)
while 1:Thread(None,C,args=s.accept()).start()
```

handles both udp and tcp.

@MorganThrapp helped saving 33 (!) chars

Comment: You can also get rid of the parens on `('',7)`. Also, move `s=S(2,2);s.bind(a)` out of `U` to save another byte.

Comment: A UDP datagram may have up to 65,507 bytes, so `999` is not enough; I suggest `4**8`.

Comment: well, afaik in practice the max size for udp packets is more around 500 bytes ..

Comment: No, in practice it’s 1472 for non-fragmented datagrams (1500 ethernet MTU − 20 byte IP header − 8 byte UDP header), but fragmented datagrams or jumbograms can be larger.

Comment: @Anders Karseorg And much more if you use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_over_Avian_Carriers   :)   -   anyway I put 4**8 and you give me an upvote, ok ?

Comment: Also consider replacing `while 1:c.send(c.recv(1))` with `while c.send(c.recv(1)):1` to handle closed TCP connections without spinning forever.

Answer (score 3):

## Racket, 231

```rkt
(thread(λ()(do([l(tcp-listen 7)])(#f)(let-values([(i o)(tcp-accept l)])(copy-port i o)))))((λ(s b)(udp-bind! s #f 7)(do()(#f)(let-values([(n h p)(udp-receive! s b)])(udp-send-to s h p b 0 n))))(udp-open-socket)(make-bytes 65535))
```

TCP and UDP.

The TCP echo server uses a handy Racket procedure named `copy-port` that copies ports in the background, managed by Racket, instead of by the programmer. That also means I don't have to spin off a thread for each client, only for the listener (so I can start the UDP listener on the main thread).